# OpenX Cluster Rsync vs Coud File System?

Tags: linux, rsync, cluster, glusterfs, openx

I am working on putting together a cluster for openx and had a question with regard to clustered file systems vs rsync.

Here is my current setup:

-2 workhorse boxes load balanced to serve and count ads (using the "distributed statistics" methodology) These servers would have their own databases that are migrated to the master database every 10 minutes.

-An Admin/Gui box Connected directly to the "master" database (just for pulling reports, trafficking, etc)

-A Database box that will be housing the databases

Once I get the servers running on the cluster, if I decided to upload a banner to the "admin" box, it only exist on the admin box only. This could cause problems when the cluster tries to pull the image. To get around this, I have thought about rsyncing the "images" directories (every 10 minutes or just setup a cluster based file system to house all of the images.

Which would be better? And is there another option that I haven't thought about?

Thanks!

I am following the methodology written here: http://blog.openx.org/10/serving-billions-of-ads-using-openx/

Answer (score 0):

If your data change often (I think so) and 2 servers is enough, you should combine a distributed file system (OCFS2, GFS) with [DRBD](http://www.drbd.org/users-guide/drbd-users-guide.html). If not, you can use rsync + [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/) when most of your data is static. If you want to add more servers, build a shared storage is another option.